# How does one plot a three-dimensional electric field in spherical coordinates?

Tags: plotting, vector, vector-calculus

I have the following three-dimensional electric field:

```
e[r_, θ_, ϕ_, t_] := (Sin[θ]/r)*(Cos[r - t] - Sin[r - t]/r)*{0, 0, 1}
```

where the {0,0,1} vector is the unit Phi vector. How can I plot the electric field lines in three-dimensional space, with spherical coordinates?

Comment: As far I know, MMA cannot plot any 3D function in other coordinate system than Cartesian. This means that your vector function in other Coordinate System should be transformed to that in a Cartesian one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generate the `TransformedField` and then plot it.

```
tf = TransformedField["Spherical"->"Cartesian",e[r,θ,φ,1],{r,θ,φ}->{x,y,z}]
VectorPlot3D[tf,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-2,2}]
```

This plots the vector field at `t==1`.

Comment: But I want to plot the field in spherical coordinates: why do you convert to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: When I run e[r_, \[Theta]_, \[CurlyPhi]_, 
   t_] := (Sin[\[Theta]]/r) [Cos[r - t] - Sin[r - t]/r] {0, 0, 1};
VectorPlot3D[
 TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  e[r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi], 
   1], {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]} -> {x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}] it returns TransformedField::nocoord: {-1.99943,-1.99943,-1.99943} is not a non-empty list of valid variables.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney Because `VectorPlot3D` doesn't have a coordinate system option, as far as I can see. I am assuming that you wish to plot the field as it would appear in a 3D space, for which this works perfectly fine (though you may need to include additional boundaries or tweaking to get precisely the shape you want). Also see edit.

Comment: OK. Why is it returning "TransformedField::nocoord: {-1.99943,-1.99943,-1.99943} is not a non-empty list of valid variables."?

Comment: It seems likely that you have r, theta, and phi defined, so `Clear` them or they will be substituted in before `TransformedField` can transform them. Alternatively, change their instances in the `VectorPlot3D` command to some consistent dummy variable names.

Comment: I Clear them but get the same result: TransformedField::nocoord: {-1.99943,-1.99943,-1.99943} is not a non-empty list of valid variables.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney It seems as though version 11 inserts the variables in a different order from version 10. I have updated my code so that shouldn't be an issue.