# Spherical Polar Coordinates VectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting, vector, coordinate-transformation

I understand the [`VectorPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) function allows you to plot a 3D vector ${Vx,Vy,Vz}$ as a function of $x,y,z$.

**Is there a function that allows you to plot in spherical polar coordinates?**

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165632/how-does-one-plot-a-three-dimensional-electric-field-in-spherical-coordinates) ?  There is also code [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-plot-3d-vector-field-in-spherical-coordinates-with-mathematica.501650/) which claims to do it. You can try and see.

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you:
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). *Which vector?*
❌: An example of what you expect as output. *Which axis?*
❌: Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge.
❌: Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.